# Temperature profile of the atmosphere due to absorption by a gas

Tags: atmospheric-science, experimental-technique, absorption

I want to observe the temperature profile of the atmosphere due to absorption by a gas such as water vapor. I know that optical thickness changes as the density of the gas changes with altitude in the atmosphere.I would greatly appreciate any suggestion to achieve my objective.

Comment: Sorry it's not clear what you mean. You want to calculate what proportion of the temperature profile is due to water vapor absorption or you want to use water vapor absorption to measure the temperature at different heights?